# true if a thread controlling or previously controlled a form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

i am programming a C# WinForm that is going to run in a framework that is not mine.

i am using a custom VS project that output a library file (.dll).

In this custom project there is a function that acts as the "main" function in a custom class and another form class.
The last line in the "main" function is always form.Closeevet.waitone(); ,so when the form is closing the thread running the "main" function should end his execution.

i am copying the library file to the main program library folder and using the main program ( that again, i didn't program), i am creating a new form from my created library file.

Under the hood the main program (called "manager") creating a form in a thread ( i don't know if this is the "manager" main thread, but all the forms created by the "manager" are created using the same thread), and creating a new thread that start running the "main" function in my created library.

this is my problem:
because this is a multi threaded environment, every time my log writeline function is called i want to add to the log file a thread name or number.
if the thread has a name, the name should be written otherwise, the thread id should be written. 
the thread that controls all the forms opened by the "manager" has no name but I still want to write in the log UI Thread every time this thread is trying to write data in the log.

this log function (and log file) is only for one form opened by the "manager", every form has his own 
log file and write functions.

my current approach is this:

```
        if (newForm!= null && !newForm.InvokeRequired) threadName = "UI";
        else if (Thread.CurrentThread.Name != null && Thread.CurrentThread.Name != "")
            threadName = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
        else threadName = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
```

the problem is, the write to log function could be called after the form has disposed (for final log data before closing the log file).
If this is happening the newForm.InvokeRequired return false even if the calling thread is not the UI thread.
so i need a function that return true  if: the current thread is controlling or previously controlled the form.
there is something that can do this?

and i don't what to change the UI thread name because I don't want to mess up with a thread that i did not created.

feel free to ask questions about this complex explanation of my situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i don't what to change the UI thread name because I don't want to mess up with a thread that i did not created

I'd argue that, even if only implicitly, you created the main (and any other) UI thread. Your program and code is the owner of that thread. I see no reason to go out of your way to avoid giving it a name.

That said, the [`Thread.ManagedThreadId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid#System_Threading_Thread_ManagedThreadId) property is invariant for a given thread. Rather than naming any threads, why not just maintain your own dictionary mapping a thread ID to a name, for the sole purpose of logging? Then each thread can specify precisely its name just for that purpose, without interfering with any other reason that code might want to name a thread, and it will work for *all* threads you want to give a name, whether you created them or not.

If you like, such an approach could even allow for the thread's name for the purpose of logging to change, depending on what that thread is actually doing at the moment, something not possible when using the [`Thread.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.name) property. For example, maybe you'd like for worker threads from the thread pool to have a name reflecting whatever the *current* entry point for that worker was, and set that name each time the worker thread is assigned a new task.